# Visual Basic - 'GetObject' Not Declared

Tags: vb.net

I've been running into an issue while attempting to update a script from VBScript to standard VB. The script simply checks for any running processes of Excel, then determines how long they've been running and shuts them down if that time has been longer than 4 minutes.
Here's the script:

```
Imports System

Module Program
    Sub Main()

        Dim objWMIService As Object, objProcess, colProcess, startDate, timeDiff

        objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
        colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & "'EXCEL.EXE'")

        For Each objProcess In colProcess
            startDate = WMIDateStringToDate(objProcess.creationdate)
            timeDiff = DateDiff("n", startDate, Now)
            If timeDiff > 4 Then
                objProcess.Terminate()
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmInstallDate As String) As Date

        WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(
                Mid(dtmInstallDate, 5, 2) & "/" &
                Mid(dtmInstallDate, 7, 2) & "/" &
                Left(dtmInstallDate, 4) & " " &
                Mid(dtmInstallDate, 9, 2) & ":" &
                Mid(dtmInstallDate, 11, 2) & ":" &
                Mid(dtmInstallDate, 13, 2))

    End Function

End Module
```

Overall, the script should work. However, there's one thing that doesn't want to work - a call to GetObject. I'm coding in Visual Studio, and it gives me the error BC30451 ('GetObject' is not declared). I understand what the error means, but my question is, why wouldn't GetObject exist? Isn't it a built-in function with Visual Basic?

I attempted switching out GetObject for CreateObject, but I got the feeling that changing it to CreateObject wouldn't help my problem. Plus I got the 'Cannot create ActiveX component' error when I did, so that was another dead end.

Am I missing something like a reference to a library or that sort of idea? Is my syntax mildly off? I've attempted to read up on the documentation, but it doesn't seem like anything is different between the docs and my code except for the Set statement before the use of GetObject. But Visual Studio tells me Let and Set are obsolete anyway.

Thank you to anyone who can help me figure this out

Comment: See the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51672117/7444103), using `System.Management`. BTW, to convert a date, you can use the [ManagementDateTimeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementdatetimeconverter) class.

Comment: Use the [WMI Code Creator utility](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572), it automatically writes the vb.net code you need.

Comment: Using the WMI Code Creator utility you suggested Hans, I've started to get things moving again. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm now having another issue where the namespaces I want to import (systems.management, etc) are running into the BC40056 error (Namespace or type specified in the imports cannot be found). Without those imports working right, some of the variable types I need aren't defined. I'm looking around on Google for what's going on. Any advice?

Comment: Have you referenced the assemblies that those types are declared in? You can't import a namespace if there are no assemblies referenced that contain declarations of member types. Without access to at least one type that is a member of a particular namespace, that namespace doesn't exist.

Comment: does the code compile? it sounds like you perhaps created a .net core console project - you want to create a Console App (.NET Framework). If createobject is compiling, and the create object fails? Then that's a different issue. What you have looks fine at least in terms of it being able to compile.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did make a .NET Core console project, so I'll try doing it again in .NET Framework

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of contribution in the comments and a bit more searching through the documentation, I was finally able to come up with a solution. The program works fully as intended. I'll post the code below, in case anyone else ever needs it:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Management

Module Program
    Sub Main()

        Dim objWMIService As New ManagementObjectSearcher(
                        "root\CIMV2",
                        "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = " & "'EXCEL.EXE'"), startDate, timeDiff

        For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In objWMIService.Get()
            Dim inParams As ManagementBaseObject =
                    queryObj.GetMethodParameters("Terminate")

            startDate = WMIDateStringToDate(queryObj("CreationDate"))
            timeDiff = DateDiff("n", startDate, Now)
            If timeDiff > 4 Then
                queryObj.InvokeMethod("Terminate", inParams, Nothing)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmInstallDate As String) As Date

        WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(
                    Mid(dtmInstallDate, 5, 2) & "/" &
                    Mid(dtmInstallDate, 7, 2) & "/" &
                    Left(dtmInstallDate, 4) & " " &
                    Mid(dtmInstallDate, 9, 2) & ":" &
                    Mid(dtmInstallDate, 11, 2) & ":" &
                    Mid(dtmInstallDate, 13, 2))

    End Function

End Module
```